# Limits of a google developer project

Tags: google-drive-api

I've a Google Developer project created and enabled drive API through which I'm uploading files to drive.

There are limits in terms of number of requests but are there any other limits in terms of size of files, total capacity... using via api for a project.

Answer (score 0):

```
The Limit Size of uploading files in Google Drive is 10 GB.
```

Google Drive offers 5 GB of free space. The Size of Google Drive can be increased. It depends on your interest. The Pricing factors are depends on the users choice.

For More details Please Check it `http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/dropbox-gdrive-skydrive/`